# Get offset of timezone in minutes

Tags: ruby, timezone

How can I get the offset of a time zone with "+10:00" or "+05:30" in Ruby or Ruby on Rails?

I have users in different time zones. Do I need to calculate the offset from their time zone, or there is a Ruby class to do that?

```
user_id   timezone
45         "+10:00"
34         "+05:30"
33         "+02:00"
32         "+00:30"
```

As you know, the time zone depends on the region. Australia uses "+10:00", India "+05:30", ... etc. What I am trying to get is the offset in minutes.

So for +10:00 the offset would be +600.

Comment: What do you have as an input and what do you want as an output? It is not clear from your question.

Comment: It is not clear to me what kind of data you already have (time zone names, the offset as a string)? And I am not sure if I understand the expected output (a string with an offset, a number)? Can you please elaborate on the input and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveSupport::TimeZone` has `utc_offset` method

> Returns the offset of this time zone from UTC in seconds.

So you can do:

```
Time.now.utc_offset / 1.minute
```

[Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-utc_offset)